# How to run tmux with shell command

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, tmux

I want to run tmux with shell command in it

I try:
`tmux new-session -d -s foo 'echo intmux'`
( I want to use this later in bash script)

But it doesn't works. I expect that:

1) Tmux open new window ( like tmux new )

2) command `echo intmux` will be called

Comment: You ran a command that completed immediately, which meant the window (and thus the session that created that window) also were immediately ended.

Comment: I'm sure there's some way to delay the code from running until you attach to the session, but I don't think any of them would really be any better than `tmux new-session -s foo 'echo intmux'`. Further, is the goal for you to have an interactive shell once `echo intmux` completes, or is that just a placeholder for some other command?

Comment: @Ruslan: any reason not to accept the good answer?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Tmux open new window ( like tmux new )

You will not see a new session, because you create it using `-d` (detached) flag.

What you want (execute a command and leave a shell open) can be easily achieved with:

`tmux new -s foo 'echo intmux; $SHELL'`

Another tricky option bound to specific (bash) shell:

```
tmux new-session -s foo 'bash --rcfile <(echo ". ~/.bashrc; echo intmux")'
```

This allows to preserve default behavior (reading `. ~/.bashrc`) and pass your arbitrary command.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out yet another option:

`tmux new-session $0 \; send-keys "echo intmux" Enter`

(instead of `$0` there can be just `bash`)

The advantage of the above is that the command is normally stored in the shell history.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can run

```
tmux new-session '-s foo' \; neww '-t 2 -n echo' mc
```

But that spawns another window in the new session running your command so possibly you want to close the first window

```
tmux new-session '-s foo' \; neww '-n echo' mc \; kill-window '-t 1'
```